# the form is not validating using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<div class="tab-pane col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" id="tab_current_employer">    
<div class="form-group"></div>
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="form_cur_employer">     
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Current Employer</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_employer" class="control-label col-lg-4">Employer</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_employer" id="cur_employer" class="form-control"/>                                      
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_title" class="control-label col-lg-4">Job Title</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_job_title" id="cur_job_title" class="form-control"/>                                     
            </div>
        </div>                          
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_address" class="control-label col-lg-4">Business Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <textarea  name="cur_job_address" id="cur_job_address" class="form-control"></textarea>                                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_state" class="control-label col-lg-4">County / State</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_job_state" id="cur_job_state" class="form-control"/>                                     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_country" class="control-label col-lg-4">Country</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_job_country" id="cur_job_country" class="form-control"/>                             
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_postcode" class="control-label col-lg-4">Post Code</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_job_postcode" id="cur_job_postcode" class="form-control"/>       
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cur_job_phone" class="control-label col-lg-4">Work Phone</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="cur_job_phone" id="cur_job_phone" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <input type="hidden" name="application_id" id="application_id" value="1"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="form_nav_back btn btn-default pull-left" href="#" data-form-tab="tab_personal_info">Previous</a>
            <a name="cur_emp_form_submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

//this is my view page i need to validate this using codeigniter in built library i tried lot of time but it is not validating. value send by json and ajax

//controller

public function sav(){

---

$this->load->model("Current_employment");
                $post_data = $this->input->post();

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="col-lg-8">', '</div>');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_employer', 'employer', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_title', 'title', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_address', 'address', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_status', 'status', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_country', 'country', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_pincode', 'pincode', 'required|integer');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cur_job_phone', 'phone', 'required|integer');
                 $lang['cur_employer']='employer';var_dump($this->lang->line('form_validation_required'));
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
       $errors=validation_errors();var_dump($errors);
               echo json_encode($errors);
    }
    else
    { 
    echo "<script>alert('Form Submitted Successfully....!!!! ');</script>";
    }

}
```

//ajax and jquery form submision and j query validation using plugin. instead of that i need codeigniter validation but not get any error message

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 /*function clear_current_employer_form()
 {
  $("#cur_employer").val("");
  $("#cur_job_title").val("");
  $("#cur_job_address").val("");
  $("#cur_job_state").val("");
  $("#cur_job_country").val("");
  $("#cur_job_postcode").val("");
  $("#cur_job_phone").val("");
 }
*/
 $(document).ready(function () {
  //save current_employer details
  $(document).on("click", "a[name='cur_emp_form_submit']", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if($("#application_id").val() == "")
   {
    alert("Unable to save! please complete first step...");
    return;
   }
   if ($("#form_cur_employer").valid())
   {
    var post_data = $("#form_cur_employer").serialize();
    ajax_start = 1;
    $(form).ajaxsubmit({
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>save-current-employer",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "json",
     data: post_data,
     success: function (data)
     {
      /*if(data.status === "invalid")
      {
       alert("Unable to save! please complete first step...");
      }
      else if ($.type(data.status) == "array")
      {
       //code for showing required validation error messages...
       //error_messages_array = {
        "cur_employer": "Please enter the current employer name ",
        "cur_job_title": "Please enter current job title",
        "cur_job_address": "Please enter the work address",
        "cur_job_state": "Please enter the state",
        "cur_job_country": "Please enter the country",
        "cur_job_postcode": "Please enter the postcode",
        "cur_job_phone": "Please enter a valid phone number"
       };
       $.each(error_messages_array, function (key, value)
       {
        //if label.error present , remove
        if ($("#" + key + "-error").length)
         $("#" + key + "-error").remove();
        if ($.inArray(key, data.status) !== -1)
        {
         var err_label = "<label id='" + key + "-error' for='" + key + "' class='error' style='display: block;'>" + value + "</label>";
         //append label.error
         $(err_label).insertAfter($("#" + key));
        }
       });*/
                                                error_array ={
                                                    "cur_employer","cur_job_title","cur_job_address","cur_job_state","cur_job_country","cur_job_postcode","cur_job_phone"
                                                };
                                               //foreach ($post_data as $key => $value)
                             // {
                                                       // if ($value == "")
                                                       //   {
                                                                   // $empty_fields[] = $key;
                                                            //    }
                                                   //}
                                                   
      else
      {
       //clear_current_employer_form();
       $("a[href='#tab_education_career']").trigger("click");
      }
     },
     error: function ()
     {

     }
    });
   }
  });

  //current employer form validation 
  //$("#form_cur_employer").validate({
   rules: {
    cur_employer: "required",
    cur_job_title: "required",
    cur_job_address: "required",
    cur_job_state: "required",
    cur_job_country: "required",
    cur_job_postcode: {
     required: true,
     number: true},
    cur_job_phone: {
     required: true,
     number: true}
   },
   //messages: {
    cur_employer: "Please enter the current employer name",
    cur_job_title: "Please enter the current job tile",
    cur_job_address: "Please enter the work address",
    cur_job_state: "Please enter the state",
    cur_job_country: "Please enter the country",
    cur_job_postcode: {
     required: "Please enter the post code",
     number: "Only numbers allowed!"},
    cur_job_phone: {
     required: "Please enter the work phone number",
     number: "Please enter a valid phone number!"}
   }
  });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: i posted my controller and fprm submision using jquery in answer and correct those error and give some assistance

Comment: any one help me.......

Answer (score 0):

You will have to show us the ajax that you are using.

I myself use the following code when I want to send data with Ajax

```
$.post( "/admin/database/ajax/edit", { id: $id, oldvalue: $oldvalue, newvalue: $valuenew, field: $field , table : "users"} );
```

Comment: check my controller and jquery and ajax form submision and validate using codeigniter